# Acts as archive does not create archive tabkle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm currently trying to use the [acts_as_archive](https://github.com/winton/acts_as_archive) gem in my rails app.

With all the rant about soft-deletable I figured it might be a more ellegant sollution to store the deleted data in an extra table...

My problem is, I have configured everything as per the minimalistic documentation but the archive tables are not created as excpected.

My model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :lead, :title
  acts_as_archive
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  acts_as_archive
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

The config/acts_as_archive.yml:

```
Article:
    - class: Article::Archive
    table: archived_articles

 Category:
    - class: Category::Archive
    table: archived_categories
```

After that i ran rake db:migrate and deleted an article in the rails console. Then i tried to access

```
Article::Archive.first
```

But got the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'archived_articles'
```

Seems like the gem is included but somehow the table is not created. Did I miss anything? I'm beginning to doubt if it is a good idea to use this gem after all because the documentation is very minimal and it seems not be active anymore....

Any thumbs up for using a soft-deletable dem like acts_as_paranoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the table doesn't seem to be present, it appears that the gem isn't installed or being loaded by Rails.

Try re-running `bundle install` to make sure that your new gem is being picked up by Rails and then re-migrate.

Comment: nope. otherwise the "Article::Archive.first" would give an undefined error. when using a fictive model like "Foo::Archive.first" this error appears, so i suppose it's installed correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Since acts_as_archive is kind of outdated, I switched to paper_trail which is not 100% the same but also supports kind off soft deletable behaiviour through the versioning system.